# Role Playing Game program: calling input variables from another class

Tags: variables, input, game-engine

I have been searching for a solution for this for hours and I'm stumped. I'm very new to Java, but I am currently programming a very easy role playing game engine. In this game, the user is to type in the level of his stats. My question is: how can I make a class where this information is stored and easily referenced when the level of the stat is called for?

To be a little more specific: I want to create a variable where the user puts in the level for his skill (using the Scanner), and then I want to let the rest of the java program access the value and use it throughout the game.

I would prefer keeping the stats in another class than where the stats will be used.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Most games have a class for the player character that contains the stats (and other stuff), is that what you want, or something else?

Comment: Oh, let me specify: the RPG system in question is classless gameplay-wise, letting you pick skills and trainings. I do want a java class to contain all that information.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
class Stats {
    private int skillLevel;
    // ... other stats
    public void setSkill(int level) { skillLevel = level }
    public int getSkill() { return skillLevel; }
}

class Player {
    private Stats stats;
    // ...
    public Stats getStats() { return stats; }
}
```

You cant then get skill for a player:

```
Player p;
// ...
p.getStats().getSkill();
```

Was it that simple or did I fail to notice something?

Comment: This answer is probably right, but I'm afraid I'm very new to Java and don't completely understand. How should I make the player specify "level"? You list "Player p;", could you please explain what this means? I think I understand most of it, but I'd like to be completely sure. Thank you for replying, and I hope to receive another answer from you!

Comment: @user969417 It's a variable declaration somewhere in the program - wherever you choose it to be. Look, I don't mean to be harsh, but there's no way you can continue without reading up on the language - look, for example, at the Java Tutorial from Oracle. All in all it's you who's going to write this game, and there's no chance you can do it on a "please send me the code" basis.

Comment: Oh, I apologize greatly if I made that impression! I do not expect anyone but myself to code this, but I figured I would be able to learn more about what I'm trying to do by asking. I will definitely check out the Java Tutorial, and thanks once again for the help!

Comment: @user969417 Don't apologize for not knowing, nobody's born a programmer. SO is the right place to ask questions, but unless you show you're actually trying hard, no one's going to help you. Do read the FAQ of SO.